# Add array to second column of another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new at Objective C. I have a list of questions, and each question has multiple answers, so I need to have an array which contains another array with a question number, then an array of answers.

I have an `NSMutableArray` which I'm instantiating it with this line:

```
_randomQuestionNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
```

I fill this array with numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    [_randomQuestionNumberArray addObject:xWrapped];
}
```

Then I have another `NSMutableArray` which is just a regular array of numbers. I want to add this array to the second column of `_randomQuestionNumberArray` at a specific row. I'm using this code for this but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
[_randomQuestionNumberArray insertObject:_tempAnswers atIndex:position];
```

Can anyone offer solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work how? What do you think a `column` in an array is? Do you really want an array or a dictionary?

Comment: When I say second column I mean second value at specific point of array..

Comment: An array is just a list of items, it doesn't contain rows and columns. That would be an array in an array. Is that what you want? What is this for?

Comment: Yes, I need to have an array in array. I have a list of questions, and each question has multiple answers, so I need to have a question number, then array of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an array of arrays. It will work initially, but it isn't flexible or clear (so hard to maintain).

Instead, use an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary has a number of keys:

```
_randomQuestionNumberArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    [_randomQuestionNumberArray addObject:[@{ @"questionNumber" : @(i) } mutableCopy]];
}
```

then, when you have your answers:

```
NSMutableDictionary *questionDict = [_randomQuestionNumberArray objectAtIndex:...];
[questionDict setObject:_tempAnswers forKey:@"answers"];
```

and now it's obvious what each piece of information is for.

*Note: the index of each item in the array could work as the question number if you wanted it to...*

Comment: Can I put the array for key "answers" ?

Comment: Certainly you can. And in the future you can add other keys (like maybe which answer is the correct one...)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;

in place of anObject put your array.

Comment: also in case of arrays we use the terminology 'index' rather than columns. I hope u mean to replace the index == 1 by an array of items.